# Deploy Bokeh Document to Server

Tags: deployment, server, panel, bokeh, renderer

I am following the example code I've attached below. It currently displays the plot and associated slider embedded in the doc returned by the "modify_doc" function in the notebook. However, I'd like to deploy it into it's own server to make a GUI, while still maintaining it's ability to run the callback when the slider is changed and update the plot. However when I try to use Panel Pyviz to deploy it, it just displays the message "< bokeh.document.document.Document object at 0x00000193EC5FFE80 >" on the server that pops up.  How do I deploy the doc in a way that will display the image?

```
import numpy as np
import holoviews as hv

from bokeh.io import show, curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import layout
from bokeh.models import Slider, Button

renderer = hv.renderer('bokeh').instance(mode='server')

# Create the holoviews app again
def sine(phase):
    xs = np.linspace(0, np.pi*4)
    return hv.Curve((xs, np.sin(xs+phase))).opts(width=800)

stream = hv.streams.Stream.define('Phase', phase=0.)()
dmap = hv.DynamicMap(sine, streams=[stream])

# Define valid function for FunctionHandler
# when deploying as script, simply attach to curdoc
def modify_doc(doc):
    # Create HoloViews plot and attach the document
    hvplot = renderer.get_plot(dmap, doc)

    # Create a slider

    def slider_update(attrname, old, new):
        # Notify the HoloViews stream of the slider update 
        stream.event(phase=new)

    start, end = 0, np.pi*2
    slider = Slider(start=start, end=end, value=start, step=0.2, title="Phase")
    slider.on_change('value', slider_update)

    # Combine the holoviews plot and widgets in a layout
    plot = layout([
    [hvplot.state],
    [slider]], sizing_mode='fixed')

    doc.add_root(plot)
    return doc

# To display in the notebook
show(modify_doc, notebook_url='localhost:8888')

# To display in a script
doc = modify_doc(curdoc()) 

# To deploy to separate server using Panel (attempt, doesn't work. Just displays #"<bokeh.document.document.Document object at 0x00000193EC5FFE80>":

graph = pn.Row (doc)
graph.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is some mixing of very different APIs going on in your example. Panel is meant to simplify some of Bokeh's APIs so a lot of what you're doing here isn't necessary. That said I'll provide a few versions which are either using only Panel components or combining Panel and bokeh components.

To start with this is how I might write this example using just Panel:

```
import numpy as np
import panel as pn
import holoviews as hv

pn.extension()

start, end = 0, np.pi*2
slider = pn.widgets.FloatSlider(start=start, end=end, value=start, step=0.2, name="Phase")

@pn.depends(phase=slider.param.value)
def sine(phase):
    xs = np.linspace(0, np.pi*4)
    return hv.Curve((xs, np.sin(xs+phase))).opts(width=800)

dmap = hv.DynamicMap(sine)

row = pn.Row(dmap, slider)

# Show in notebook
row.app('localhost:8888')

# Open a server
row.show()

# To deploy this using `panel serve` or `bokeh serve`
row.servable()
```

In your example you instead use various bokeh components, this is also possible and might be desirable if you've already got bokeh code.

```
import numpy as np
import holoviews as hv
import panel as pn

from bokeh.models import Slider, Button

# Create the holoviews app again
def sine(phase):
    xs = np.linspace(0, np.pi*4)
    return hv.Curve((xs, np.sin(xs+phase))).opts(width=800)

stream = hv.streams.Stream.define('Phase', phase=0.)()
dmap = hv.DynamicMap(sine, streams=[stream])

def slider_update(attrname, old, new):
    # Notify the HoloViews stream of the slider update 
    stream.event(phase=new)

start, end = 0, np.pi*2
slider = Slider(start=start, end=end, value=start, step=0.2, title="Phase")
slider.on_change('value', slider_update)

graph = pn.Row(dmap, slider)

# Show in notebook
row.app('localhost:8888')

# Open a server
row.show()

# To deploy this using `panel serve` or `bokeh serve`
row.servable()
```

If you want to serve these apps to multiple people I'd definitely recommend using `panel serve` but if you really want to make a script you can run with `python script.py` you should do this:

```
def app():
    start, end = 0, np.pi*2
    slider = pn.widgets.FloatSlider(start=start, end=end, value=start, step=0.2, name="Phase")

    @pn.depends(phase=slider.param.value)
    def sine(phase):
        xs = np.linspace(0, np.pi*4)
        return hv.Curve((xs, np.sin(xs+phase))).opts(width=800)

    dmap = hv.DynamicMap(sine)
    return pn.Row(dmap, slider)

pn.serve({'/': app})
```

This requires latest Panel, but ensures that even if you run the app as a script that each user gets a new instance of the app which does not share state with all others.